# Restore precompiled header

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, precompiled-headers

I have a C++ console project that I included a precompiled header in the setup. I accidentally deleted the file from my project and now I can't compile because I get `error C1083: Cannot open precompiled header file: 'Debug\Project.pch': No such file or directory`. Do I have to re-create the project and import all the code into it? I tried re-creating a file named "stdafx.cpp" that contains only `#include "stdafx.h"`, but that does not work. How do I fix this?

Comment: Writing code without using source control is a Really Bad Idea.  These accidents happen, source control is your fallback.

Comment: Seems tangential, you wouldn't check machine-specific generated files (like pre-compiled headers) into source control.

Comment: @HansPassant This is just a minor project; I use Git for most of my projects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right-click stdafx.cpp in Solution Explorer and choose Properties. Under C/C++ > Precompiled Headers, set "Precompiled Header" to "Create (/Yc)". You may also need to set "Precompiled Header File" to "stdafx.h" and "Precompiled Header Output File" to whatever makes sense ("$(IntDir)$(TargetName).pch" in most cases).

Unless there are other issues too, that should do it.

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly!

Comment: You're welcome. I spent quite a while trying to solve the same problem back in the day, and am happy to save someone else the trouble.